# How to Distinct a sql query but still return all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query:

```
SELECT dbo.Webs.Id, dbo.Webs.Title, dbo.Webs.FullUrl, dbo.Roles.RoleId,
       dbo.Roles.Title AS RoleTitle, dbo.UserInfo.tp_Title, dbo.UserInfo.tp_Login
FROM dbo.RoleAssignment
  INNER JOIN dbo.Roles ON dbo.RoleAssignment.SiteId = dbo.Roles.SiteId
                      AND dbo.RoleAssignment.RoleId = dbo.Roles.RoleId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Webs ON dbo.Roles.SiteId = dbo.Webs.SiteId
                     AND dbo.Roles.WebId = dbo.Webs.Id
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserInfo ON dbo.RoleAssignment.PrincipalId = dbo.UserInfo.tp_ID
WHERE tp_Title = 'HOBSON, Will';
```

This database contains all the permissions for the users of all sharepoint sites. I'm trying to create a query that displays all sites the user has access to. Currently it outputs a lot of duplicate information. I only want it to display results that have either a distinct Role Title or a distinct Web id.

[image: query results]

So for example, in this query I would only want to see 4 results; 1, 5, 11 and 13.

(all this information is on a local test SharePoint installation that cannot be accessed externally, so the only information I'm giving away here is my name :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query would be much easier to read with table aliases.  The direct answer to your question is to use `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.Id, w.Title, w.FullUrl, r.RoleId, r.Title AS RoleTitle,
       ui.tp_Title, ui.tp_Login
FROM dbo.RoleAssignment ra INNER JOIN
     dbo.Roles r
     ON ra.SiteId = r.SiteId AND
        ra.RoleId = r.RoleId INNER JOIN
     dbo.Webs w
     ON r.SiteId = w.SiteId AND
        r.WebId = w.Id INNER JOIN
     dbo.UserInfo ui
     ON ra.PrincipalId = ui.tp_ID
WHERE tp_Title = 'HOBSON, Will';
```

However, it would be better to find the cause of the duplicates.  Often duplicates like this are caused by incomplete join conditions.  Fixing the join is the better approach, but sometimes `SELECT DISTINCT` is necessary.

Comment: Also, if one uses GROUP BY instead of SELECT DISTINCT then a subsequent programmer is less likely to think the code written by an amateur who doesn't understand the bad-join point you make. SELECT DISTINCT screams ***amateur coder*** to most SQL programmers.

Comment: Oh cool that was easier to fix than expected, while i'm here, would it be possible to display only the entry with the highest role. (it would have the largest RoleID

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, and I'd say that GROUP BY without any aggregate functions is really bad practice...

Comment: @jarlh: OK; different backgrounds, different colleagues, different experiences. Less universal than I thought. In Data Mining I have used SELECT DISTINCT to indicate that the cause of duplicates is undetermined, needing investigation; GROUP BY where the cause has been determined to be benign, and unresolvable by other means.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `DISTINCT` to your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Webs.Id, dbo.Webs.Title, dbo.Webs.FullUrl, dbo.Roles.RoleId,
       dbo.Roles.Title AS RoleTitle, dbo.UserInfo.tp_Title, dbo.UserInfo.tp_Login
FROM dbo.RoleAssignment
  INNER JOIN dbo.Roles ON dbo.RoleAssignment.SiteId = dbo.Roles.SiteId
                      AND dbo.RoleAssignment.RoleId = dbo.Roles.RoleId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Webs ON dbo.Roles.SiteId = dbo.Webs.SiteId
                     AND dbo.Roles.WebId = dbo.Webs.Id
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserInfo ON dbo.RoleAssignment.PrincipalId = dbo.UserInfo.tp_ID
WHERE tp_Title = 'HOBSON, Will';
```